# Numpy 2d ndarray sort by a given specific 2d array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

Say I have given two 2d ndarray like this:

```
import numpy as np 
refer_array = np.array([[1, 4],
                        [3, 1],
                        [3, 2],
                        [3, 3],
                        [3, 4],
                        [1, 2],
                        [1, 3],
                        [2, 2],
                        [4, 2],
                        [5, 2],
                        [1, 0]])
A = np.array([[3, 2],
              [3, 1],
              [1, 2],
              [1, 4],
              [3, 3],
              [3, 4]])
```

What I want to do is to sort A based on the order of refer_array, so the result should be like:

```
A_sorted = array([[1, 4],
                  [3, 1],
                  [3, 2],
                  [3, 3],
                  [3, 4],
                  [1, 2])
```

I appreciate any one who could solve my problem or give me some clue.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on how `A_sorted` is sorted according to `refer_array`?

Comment: I mean that all the A 's elements(rows) are in refer_array, but they are not in the "order" like those in refer_array. What I want is some method to "sort" A's rows to A_sorted, which rows are in the order exactly like they should be in refer_array. I hope this is clear for you. Thank you.

Comment: Are they always going to be unique? If so - that's more a filter `refer_array` to only items that exist in `A` rather than an actual sort...

Comment: Use `refer_array[isin_nd(refer_array,A)]` from linked Q&A.

Comment: A simpler example, say we have an 1d reference array: [4,7,2,9,0], and an array A: [2,4,9]. I want to turn A into A_sorted:[4,2,9] by some method, where A_sorted's each element is exacty the "order" they should be in reference array.

Comment: @JonClements Yes, you can say that

Comment: @Divakar This approach fits. Thank you very much!